# JavaMail cannot send email

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

i am trying to write an application in java that will send emails, i found a tutorial on youtube and tried to follow it. however it does not work for me still, here is the error i get

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25, response: 421
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1949)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at libraryFineList.ParseRecords.main(ParseRecords.java:90)
```

i have no idea, what's wrong, anything i found on google did not help,

here is the code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
            new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
        protected  PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user@gmail.com", "pass");

        }
    }

            );

    try{
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user@gmail.com"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   new InternetAddress("ycharnetskaya@gmail.com", "Mr. User"));
        message.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
        message.setText("Worked");
  Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: here are the libraries that i downloaded and added to build path]

[image]

Comment: Worked for me (javax.mail 1.5.2).  Sure you don't have firewall or router issues?

Comment: Have you also considered trying a new port 587 for example, but the error message doesn't really match your source code

Comment: @MadProgrammer just tried the error is exactly the same, what kind of issues i can have with firewall or router?

Comment: It's possible that a router or firewall is blocking access to a particular port.  What do you get when you `ping smtp.gmail.com`?  Because you shouldn't be getting an error saying `localhost`....

Comment: @MadProgrammer posted the ping result

Comment: The ping is correct. What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: This is so strange it's almost as if you're running an old version of the .class file.  Have you tried deleting the binaries, recompiling and re-running?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i am running 1.4.7 i guess i ll get a newer one, it looked like it was the latest when i got it, i will try later and tell the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you followed is full of errors.  Start by fixing these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Then follow these [instructions for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  If you're still having problems, you'll find lots more help in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).  There's also many [sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) available.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that your error message is complaining about a problem connecting to localhost:25 when your properties file is clearly suggesting that you should use smtp.gmail.com.

I don't suppose there's anything dodgy going on with your hosts file that's redirecting smtp.gmail.com back to 127.0.0.1 or something, is there?  What happens if you `ping smtp.gmail.com` from the command line?

Apart from that, I'd suggest checking you're using the latest version of Java Mail.